# Huge Server Response Time (12s) after Wordpress Posts Import (~ 1000 Posts)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, server-response

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask a question here that is not related to coding per se?
I'm trying still though, maybe someone can give me a tipp.

I'm running an EC2 t3.medium machine for a "simple" wordpress blog - literally a blog with no other post-types. There is an existing version of the site and I wanted to import the old posts via "Tools>Export" and "Tools>Import".

However the site now is super slow. I have no redirection issues as I tested for those, but when running Lighthouse Audits I get almost 12s server response time.

Any ideas how this could happen?
Also for context, only 3 Plugins active, simple theme, nothing special.
I imported ~ 1000 old "posts" that should remain in the archive of this blog.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Please take a look if your postmeta table/wp_option are exploded by the mean that they have a weird high number of rows compared to the posts (just to check that nothing went wrong during the import)

Comment: @Diego thanks for your feedback: see https://i.imgur.com/2pfhb4N.png … again, this is obviously a super fast machine for a small wordpress site but I need to keep the post archive to keep it available for users. That's why I'm importing all old posts.

Comment: What's the weight in terms of disk space occupied by the wp_postmeta table? because i fear that 290k rows in there are killing your wordpress. Like everything wp does goes through that table so if it size increase too much it will start to suffer. Can't think of anything else since as you said it's like an empty installation

Comment: The size on the harddrive with also imported media is close to 20gb